# Using SWIG to Wrap C++ Function With Default Values

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linux, g++, swig

I have the following C++ function in `say.hpp`:

```
#include <iostream>


void say(const char* text, const uint32_t x = 16, const uint32_t y = 24, const int32_t z = -1) {
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

Here is my `say.i`:

```
%module say
%{
#include "say.hpp"
%}

%include "say.hpp"
```

Then, I built the shared library:

```
$ swig -python -c++ -I/usr/include say.i
$ g++ -fPIC -c say_wrap.cxx -I/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/include/python3.8 
$ g++ -shared say_wrap.o -o _say.so
```

Then, I tried to call it:

```
>>> import say
>>> say.say("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hc/test/cpp/say.py", line 66, in say
    return _say.say(text, x, y, z)
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'say'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    say(char const *,uint32_t const,uint32_t const,int32_t const)
    say(char const *,uint32_t const,uint32_t const)
    say(char const *,uint32_t const)
    say(char const *)

>>>
```

It seems something is wrong with having default values for the function parameters as once I remove them, it works.

Any idea?

Comment: The C++ code that you show, is that the contents of the `say.hpp` file?

Comment: yes, I just tried to keep things simple to have everything in the header.

Comment: Can you verify if the overloaded methods are generated correctly (- as stated [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_default_args))

Comment: Have you tried it with 'compactdefaultargs' feature-flag?

Comment: @ttuna how can I verify?  I looked into the generated python file `say.py`, and I only see one definition -- `def say(text, x=16, y=24, z=-1):`

Comment: I am not familiar with the feature flag.  So I append `%feature("compactdefaultargs") say;` to `say.i` above?  If yes, I just tried.  Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `say.i` file.  SWIG has prewritten code for the standard integer types and needs it included to understand them.  Without them, the wrapper receives the default values as opaque Python objects and doesn't know how to convert them to the correct C++ integer types.

```cpp
%module say
%{
#include "say.hpp"
%}
%include <stdint.i>
%include "say.hpp"
```

Result:

```py
>>> import say
>>> say.say('hello')
hello
>>> say.say('hello',1,2,3)
hello
```

Note you could also supply the typedefs directly, but better to use `stdint.i`:

```
%module say
%{
#include "say.hpp"
%}
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef int int32_t;
%include "say.hpp"
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works.  I am confused what needs to be '%include', and what doesn't.  Mind elaborating?

Comment: @HCSF SWIG is a C/C++ parser. It creates wrappers for whatever it parses, but code between %{/%} is inserted into the wrapper without generating wrappers. So `#include "say.hpp"` makes your function known to the wrapper, but generates no interfaces. `%include "say.hpp"` processes the code directly in the file into wrapped interfaces  (not recursively, like iostream is ignored). SWIG only understands basic types but is forgiving, so in your case the stdint types were  wrapped as opaque pointers that the C++code didn’t understand.

Comment: @HCSF SWIG understands typedefs and basic types, and stdint.i has a number of typedefs for the stdint types, so it had to be included to make SWIG aware that they are equivalent to predefined types. Adding then manually also works.

Comment: `%include "say.hpp" processes the code directly in the file into wrapped interfaces (not recursively, like iostream is ignored)`.  So it sounds like all the `#include` directives in `say.hpp` should be included via `%include` in `say.i`?  It seems not.  So what's the rule/guideline for it?  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF Only if you want all of iostream wrapped (usually not, and wouldn’t work anyway, much more complicated interfaces), but if there was some other  definitions you need in a sub-include, then yes.  Include exactly what you need to wrap. If you only need one function, copy its prototype into the .i instead of including the whole file if you want